# read a file into a list, each element represents one line of the file

Tags: file-io, clojure

In clojure, how do I read a file into a sequence where each line is one element in the sequence.  So I'd like to see the definition of the function `get-lines` so I could do the following:

```
(def lines (get-lines "test.txt"))
```

and lines is a non-lazy sequence.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To convert lazy sequence to non-lazy you can use `doall` like so:

```
(use 'clojure.java.io)

(defn get-lines [fname]
  (with-open [r (reader fname)]
    (doall (line-seq r))))
```

Answer (score 12):

Alternate implementation:

```
(require ['clojure.string :as 'str])

(defn get-lines [file]
  (str/split-lines (slurp file)))
```

This function returns a vector of the results instead of a seq.

If you are not using 1.3, require clojure.contrib.string instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`line-seq`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/line-seq). A quick example:

```
(ns your.project
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io]))

(defn count-lines [filename]
  (with-open [rdr (io/reader filename)]
    (count (line-seq rdr))))
```

Note that `line-seq` is [lazy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation). You must be careful not to consume the sequence *after* the reader is closed. The following will not work:

```
(def lines (with-open [rdr (io/reader "some-file")]
             (line-seq rdr)))

(println (first lines))
```

The first example works because `count` isn't lazy.

If you want to do something (with side effects) with the lines you'll probably find [`doseq`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/doseq) most useful:

```
;; copy every "short" line in file
(with-open [rdr (io/reader from)
            wrt (io/writer to)]
  (binding [*out* wrt]
    (doseq [line (line-seq rdr) :when (< (count line) 10)]
      (println line))))
```

Comment: The: doall, was the key I was looking for.  I needed a list that was intact/usable after the with-open closed the file.